# Show count of rows with same values

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE clicks
(
    Year UInt16,
    Week UInt8,
    Day UInt8,
    Month UInt8,
    ClickDate Date,
    ClickTime DateTime,
    AdvertId String,
    UserId String,
    Age UInt8,
    Country FixedString(2),
    Gender Enum8('male' = 1, 'female' = 2),
    Ip String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree(ClickDate, (Year, ClickDate), 8192);
```

Is it possible to add for one column with sum of rows for one unique value without duplication of values and group them by `ClickDate`? E.g. I have query:

```
SELECT 
    count() AS Summary, 
    ClickDate, 
    SUM(roundAge(Age) = 17) AS Age_17, 
    SUM(roundAge(Age) = 25) AS Age_25, 
    SUM(roundAge(Age) = 35) AS Age_35, 
    SUM(roundAge(Age) = 45) AS Age_45, 
    SUM(Age = 0) AS Age_empty
FROM clicks 
GROUP BY ClickDate
```

In this case, I need to duplicate each of `Age` values

```
SUM(roundAge(Age) = 17) AS Age_17, 
SUM(roundAge(Age) = 25) AS Age_25
```

How can I get rid of this duplication? What I expect:

Source data:

```
┌──ClickDate─┬─RoundedAge─┐
│ 2016-10-09 │         17 │
└────────────┴────────────┘
┌──ClickDate─┬─RoundedAge─┐
│ 2016-10-09 │         25 │
│ 2016-10-09 │         17 │
│ 2016-10-09 │         45 │
│ 2016-10-09 │         45 │
│ 2016-10-09 │         35 │
│ 2016-10-09 │         45 │
│ 2016-10-09 │         25 │
│ 2016-10-09 │         18 │
│ 2016-10-10 │         25 │
│ 2016-10-10 │         25 │
└────────────┴────────────┘
┌──ClickDate─┬─RoundedAge─┐
│ 2016-10-09 │         17 │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

Required output:

```
┌─Summary─┬──ClickDate─┬─Age_17─┬─Age_25─┬─Age_35─┬─Age_45─┬─Age_empty─┐
│      10 │ 2016-10-09 │      3 │      2 │      1 │      3 │         0 │
│       2 │ 2016-10-10 │      0 │      2 │      0 │      0 │         0 │
└─────────┴────────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: I think you should use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`. In PostgreSQL you can count boolean expressions by appending `OR NULL`, e.g.  `COUNT(roundAge(Age) = 17 OR NULL)`. Don't know if this works in other DBMS.

Comment: In Clickhouse `COUNT` does not accept arguments :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for being slowpoke, I can't provide you magic.
But, that looks better:

```
SELECT 
    count() AS Summary, 
    ClickDate, 
    countIf(Age = 17), 
    countIf(Age = 25), 
    countIf(Age = 35), 
    countIf(Age = 45), 
    SUM(Age = 0) AS Age_empty
FROM clicks 
GROUP BY ClickDate
```

I just used Combinator "If". I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE WHEN

```
  SELECT 
  count(*) AS Summary, 
  ClickDate, 
  sum( case when age = 17 then 1 else 0 end),  Age_17,
  sum( case when age = 25 then 1 else 0 end),  Age_25,   
  sum( case when age = 35 then 1 else 0 end),  Age_35,
  sum( case when age = 45 then 1 else 0 end),  Age_45,   
  sum( case when ifnull(age,0) = 0 then 1 else 0 end)  Age_Empty       
  FROM clicks 
  GROUP BY ClickDate
```

and if you need  range you can use between

```
  SELECT 
  count(*) AS Summary, 
  ClickDate, 
  sum( case when age between 1  and 17 then 1 else 0 end),  Age_17,
  sum( case when age between 18 and 25 then 1 else 0 end),  Age_25,   
  sum( case when age between 26 and 35 then 1 else 0 end),  Age_35,
  sum( case when age between 36 and 45 then 1 else 0 end),  Age_45,   
  sum( case when ifnull(age,0) = 0 then 1 else 0 end)  Age_Empty       
  FROM clicks 
  GROUP BY ClickDate
```

Comment: It's useless, because I still have specify the value. What if I do not know possible values in `Age`?

Comment: you have a range ?   .

Comment: Ok, what if I need to use `IP` / `Country` column instead of `Age`? I do not know expected values.

Comment: Is the same you can use between  for each column . the result is evaluated based or the natural order for data .. type  ,,, but this seems another answer ..